# How to use alias 'as' with knex js select

Tags: node.js, reactjs, knex.js

I need to return a specific json structure to the frontend and in order to do that I need something like

```
knex.select('status as x')
```

I've looked at Knex js docs but didn't find anything useful, besides that I've also googled a lot trying to find some example that my be the answer to my questions but didn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind.

I found the answer right after posting the question. In case anyone runs into the same question, you want something like: `knex.select(['status as x'])`

Comment: It's actually `knex.select(['status as x'])`. Remove the two `'` in the middle